# How To Add Event Listener OnChange Using Custom Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, addeventlistener

Please help me for my problem in select option. I want to know how to get value from select option and showing in label like my second select option in this link or my snippet, I am trying to get value from select option with Onchange event listener, but it's not working. Any idea how to solve this problem?
Here is my snippet :

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
            l = x.length;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                ll = selElmnt.length;
                /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
                a = document.createElement("DIV");
                a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
                a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
                x[i].appendChild(a);
                /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
                for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
                    /*for each option in the original select element,create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
                    c = document.createElement("DIV");
                    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
                    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,and the selected item:*/
                        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
                        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                        sl = s.length;
                        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
                            if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                                s.selectedIndex = i;
                /*var h is get selected value*/
                                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                                yl = y.length;
                                for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                                    y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                                }
                                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                            h.addEventListener("change", function(e){
                 getsize();
              });
              console.log(h); 
                            });
                            b.appendChild(c);
                        }
                            x[i].appendChild(b);
                            a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                            /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,and open/close the current select box:*/
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            closeAllSelect(this);
                            this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
                            this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
                        });
                    }

        function getsize() {
                var dom = document.getElementByClassname("select-arrow-active").value; 
                document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "You selected : " + dom;
                console.log(dom); 
        } 

                function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
                /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,except the current select box:*/
                var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
                x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
                y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
                xl = x.length;
                yl = y.length;
                for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
                    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                        arrNo.push(i);
                    } else {
                         y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
                    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                        x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
                    }
                }
            }
            /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,then close all select boxes:*/
            document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
    
 /*JS For Second Select Option*/
 document.getElementById("size_b").onchange = function() {
    getsize3();
};
function getsize3() {
  var dom3 = document.getElementById("size_b").value;
  document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "You selected : " + dom3;
}
```

```css
.custom-select {
        position: relative;
        font-family: SterlingDisplay;
        color: #999999;
}

.custom-select select {
        display: none; /*hide original SELECT element*/
}

.select-selected {
        background-color: white;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 6px solid transparent;
        border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
        border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
        top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
        color: #999999;
        padding: 7px 15px 7px 5px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: #a87c4f;
        border-radius: 7px;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
        display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover{
        background-color: #999999;
        color: red;
}
                     .select-selected {
        background-color: white;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 14px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 6px solid transparent;
        border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
        border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
        top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
        color: #999999;
        padding: 7px 15px 7px 5px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: #a87c4f;
        border-radius: 7px;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
      position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
        display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover{
        background-color: #999999;
        color: red;
}

.selectsize {
  font-family: AvenirNextRegular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999999;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #a87c4f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.optionsize {
  color: #231f1c !important;
}
.optionsize:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<label>This is a My First Select Option Problem : </label>
<div class="custom-select mb-8" style="width:100%;">
  <select id="size_a" style="padding-left: 5px;">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
    <option value="f">f</option>
    <option value="g">g</option>
    <option value="h">h</option>
  </select>
</div>
<label id="1" style="color: red">No Item Selected</label><br />

<label>This is a My Second Select Option What I Want, but i dont want this select option because some issue</label><br />
<select class="selectsize" id="size_b">
  <option class"optionsize" value="">Choose</option>
  <option class"optionsize" value="a">a</option>
  <option class"optionsize" value="b">b</option>
  <option class"optionsize" value="c">c</option>
</select><br />
<label id="3" style="color: red">No Item Selected</label>
```

No Item Selected

here is the link of my simple project :
[My Custom Select Option](https://codepen.io/ionix12/pen/ZELLMGX)

I hope someone will be help me for this problem, Thank You.